# How to redirect in redux after registration?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, redux

I have created a signup form in react redux and it works as expected. The problem is that I have tried to push `/` in hash route to redirect user to dashboard, but it gives an error. I even used `router` in context as below:

```
if (this.isValid()) {
      // dispatching request for user sing up
      this.props.userSignupRequest(this.state)
          .then(response => {
              this.setState({isLoading: false});
              this.context.router.replaceWith('/');
          })
          .catch(error => {
              this.setState({errors: error.response.data, isLoading: false});
          });
  }
```

In the `Register` component file that I have written the above code, I have the below code as well (outside of component class):

```
Register.contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

This does not give any error. How should I implement the redirect? It seems that `react-router` behaves differently in newer version.

Version: `"react-redux": "^5.0.6"`

Comment: *"it gives an error"* - what error?

Comment: Also, assuming you're using React Router, I'm pretty certain that you're not meant to access the router via context - have you read [the docs on how to do redirects](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you should use one of the way below: 
1) Use react-router-redux - https://github.com/reacttraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux and you can create action and inside action you can use

```
import {push} from 'react-router-redux'

const goTo = (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(push('/'));
}
```

2) You can use  component to redirect to some url:

```
  load(){
    if (this.isValid()) {
      // dispatching request for user sing up
      this.props.userSignupRequest(this.state)
          .then(response => {
              this.setState({isLoading: false, goTo: '/'});
          })
    }
  }

  render(){
    const {isLoading, goTo} = this.state;

    return goTo? <Redirect to={goTo} /> : (
       <div>Component</div>
    )
  }
```